# subset df on specified values and preceding values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm aiming to subset a df on specific values. Using below, these are recorded in `items`, which are `B` and `D`. I'm also hoping to subset the rows preceding `B` and `D` that are recorded in `other_items` (`X`, `Y`). Note: I only want to return the last preceding item before `B` or `D`. So they last `X`, `Y` before `B`, `D`.

Essentially, find every row that contains `B` or `D` and return the last preceding row that equals `X` or `Y`. The problem is it could be anywhere between 1-10 rows beforehand.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({   
    'Val' : [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4],             
    'ID' : ['X','Y','B','X','C','X','C','D','E','Y','Y','A','B','C','X','C','Y','D','E','A'],                 
    })

items = ['B','D']

other_items = ['X','Y']

df = df.loc[(df['ID'].isin(items)) | df['ID'].shift(-1).isin(items) & (df['ID'].isin(other_items))]
```

Intended Output:

```
    Val ID
1     1  Y
2     1  B
5     2  X
7     2  D
10    3  Y
12    3  B
16    4  Y
17    4  D
```

Comment: Do you need processing solution per groups by `Val` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First filter only rows by summed both lists and then filter by previous and next values:

```
items = ['B','D']
other_items = ['X','Y']

df = df[df['ID'].isin(other_items + items)]

m1 = df['ID'].isin(other_items) & df['ID'].shift(-1).isin(items)
m2 = df['ID'].isin(items) & df['ID'].shift().isin(other_items)
```

If need processing per groups:

```
m1 = df['ID'].isin(other_items) & df.groupby('Val')['ID'].shift(-1).isin(items)
m2 = df['ID'].isin(items) & df.groupby('Val')['ID'].shift().isin(other_items)
```

And last filter:

```
df = df[m1 | m2]
print (df)
    Val ID
1     1  Y
2     1  B
5     2  X
7     2  D
10    3  Y
12    3  B
16    4  Y
17    4  D
```

Comment: nice! beat me to it +1. However, I'm going to guess the OP wants it by group, which you have already asked as a comment as well ;)